# Dfs maze generation, optimization?

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, maze

I am trying to learn to implement all of the maze generation algorithms one by one, my first maze generation algorithm was dfs backtracking ( non recursive ) and i am done with the implementation, i have used cpp and sfml for it.

I optimized it by using 1d vector and bit fields and the final results for rendering a maze of 9000 x 9000 with a cell size of 2 is around 1 min and 46 seconds ( directly writing to image no gui ).

Can this be still improved? ( I think my image writing method is quite slow. )

Comment: Everything can be improved; can you show your code?

Comment: @VladFeinstein here you go : https://github.com/irrevocablesake/maze_generator/blob/master/Maze.cpp

The draw maze function is the main logic ( second last function ) and i use two stacks btx and bty to store all of the visited position to backtrack in those stacks.

There are three possible ways to generate :

1-> animate at a certain fps
0-> do not animate but directly pop up the maze on the screen
-1->do not animate and do not show a pop up of the maze on the screen

Comment: I am getting 404...

Comment: @VladFeinstein try again in a min or two, i'll do something about it

Comment: @VladFeinstein here you go : https://github.com/irrevocablesake/maze/blob/master/main.cpp

Comment: What exactly are you measuring? I don't see any use of `chrono`

Comment: @VladFeinstein nothing, it was for manual delay between frames but i removed it and the relevant code except the declarations

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask: what is taking `1 min and 46 seconds`? What did you measure? `void Maze::saveImage()`?

Comment: @VladFeinstein The entire program takes around 1 min 46 seconds from starting to saving image and then i commented out the image saving section so it reduced the runtime by 30 seconds.

So i would say it take around a minute and 13 seconds for the logic part i.e the drawMaze() and around 30 seconds for image saving

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct? Does `int Maze::invalidNeighbour(int x,int y,char dir)` check validity of the (x,y) in a given direction? Why is condition the same for `top` and `bottom` (and for `left` and `right`)? You can't go up from row 0, for example...

Comment: @VladFeinstein yes 100% , i have already generated mazes here is one : https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/721031563370037248/751053092035887164/mazeSolver.gif

Comment: @VladFeinstein oh i got it what you are talking about, so the thing is the 2d array is represented here in the form of a 1d array, if we see it in the terms off 2d array like an element in [1][0] there is no element on the left so it should check to the left of the current element but the same thing in the 1d array would give us a legal element making the maze a bit weird so that is why the logic is that.

The invalid neighbour just checks if a given coodinate are inside 0,0 and the max,max
but since we use 1d arrays we need to use an additional parameter direction.
Hope, i mademyselfclear

Comment: No, not clear at all. From the context, it looks like your `int Maze::invalidNeighbour(int x,int y,char dir)` should answer a question: can I go into direction `dir` from a given point, is that right? Then you should have *different* conditions for `t` and `b`! If you CAN go up, it doesn't mean that you also can go down...

Comment: @VladFeinstein its not choosing any direction it's just checking if the given cell exists or if it's out of bounds that is it and if it exists and if it's the cell is to the right or left we just check if the cell is in the same row as the current cell cause if not the maze path would be jumping around and in the case of top and bottom we just do that cause if there is'nt a top the index will surely go out of bounds cause the new choosen cell will be right above the current cell and same goes with the bottom cell checking

Comment: Generating a 9K x 9K maze in C++ with DFS backtracking should take much less than 1 second.

Comment: @MattTimmermans yes, you are absolutely correct i made changes to the code and the algorithm is blazing fast, will update on github when possible

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to follow the logic in your code. Looks like in `Maze::checkNeighbours` you use `x` and `y` as coordinates (where `x` for some reason is vertical), while in `Maze::invalidNeighbour` `x` is new linear offset and `y` is old?

Anyway, you can remove all that math and replace your conditions as follows:

- `if(top)` -> `if(x > 0)`
- `if(right)` -> `if(y + 1 < cols)`
- `if(bottom)` -> `if(x + 1 < rows)`
- `if(left)` -> `if(y > 0)`
  As this are used a lot of time, you may save some time.

I am not sure how compiler would optimize your frequent creation of `sf::Vector2f` and their assignment to another `sf::Vector2f`; even if they are moved, you lost time on constructing them in the first place. So, instead of:

```
Quad[counter].position = sf::Vector2f((j*cellSize)+padding, (i*cellSize)+cellSize+padding);
```

I would do:

```
Quad[counter].position.x = (j*cellSize)+padding;
Quad[counter].position.y = (i*cellSize)+cellSize+padding;
```

Since you have a dozen of those, executed millions of times, my guess is that you will see some improvement.

Then you can avoid multiplications in `(j*cellSize)` and `(i*cellSize)` by replacing them with the increment in the `for` statements, like:

```
for(int i=0, iScaled=0; i<rows; i++, iScaled += cellSize)
{
    for(int j=0, jScaled = 0; j<cols; j++, jScaled += cellSize)
```

Your compiler would probably do that, but I think it will make it easier to read.

```
Quad[counter].position.x = jScaled+padding;
Quad[counter].position.y = iScaled+cellSize+padding;
```

I would also like to see your `turnOnBit`, `turnOffBit` and `checkBit` as they are called a LOT.

As for saving the image, although I don't know sfml, using `SetPixel` is typically very bad for performance. Looks like there is [sf::Image::loadFromMemory](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Image.php#aaa6c7afa5851a51cec6ab438faa7354c). Can you arrange your internal representation of the maze so it could just be loaded?

**[CORRECTION]** My micro-optimizations didn't make much difference; as expected - the compiler optimization took care of that.

However, I ran a profiler and noticed that most of the time is spent in GL and GDI. Then I change the fps rate from 25 to 250 and got 10 times performance improvement! Could it be that `window.display();` throttles your loop?If I change the fps to 2, it slows down to a crawl...

Comment: hello thanks for the help unfortunetly the micro-optimizations don't make huge difference, i had already tried that but i changed some parts of the dfs and the algorithm is blazing fast now will update on github when possible